# Load the JQgrid, by default it is should show 10 rows, but it is display 20 rows while Load the grid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

when I load the **JQgrid**, it should display only **10 rows**, But it is displaying **20 rows** while loading the grid as default. Even in the footer setting as **10 rows** only.

**why it's displaying 20 Rows in default?** If I change it as **10 rows** manualy, it's getting change.

In image you can see the marked places **(Page (1 of 10) rows)**, but **20 columns** got displayed. In **(View (1 - 20 of 76)rows)**.
 [Imperfect_JQgrid_**Rows**_Loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJyIQ.png) &
 [Perfect_JQgrid_**Rows**_Loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0R83.png)

Comment: It's absolutely unclear how you fill the grid. You should append your question with the code which you use. If you load the data from the server then you should include an example of JSON or XML response returned from the server.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly then you need to check your jqGrid parameters: rowNum, rowList

if you have following configuration then it will fetch 20 records from server and display in grid and also view records will display (1-20 of...) right, but as you do not have matching value in rowList array it will by default select 10 (first value).

```
    ...
    rowNum: 20,     
    rowList: [10,50,100,200],
    ...
```

so if you put 20 in rowList or change rowNum to one of the value from rowList will fix your issue.

To correct configure as following,

```
    ...
    rowNum: 20,     
    rowList: [10,20,50,100,200],
    ...
```